# Can not get my data from my form in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, I am trying to have a simple example, but I am getting a 419 error, I dont know why it shows up but I will expalin what I did,
I created a simple Controller and I called it FormController with the command line :

```
 php artisan make:controller --resource FormController
```

In my web.php I added this :

```
Route::resource('form','FormController');
```

my view has a simple form in it :

```
<form action="/form" method="POST" >
   <input type="text" name="cih">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I open my view with the create method :

```
public function create()
{
    return view('contact');
}
```

I want that when I submit my form I get my data, so I use my 'store' method :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

But instead of getting it, I get 419 message, and my session has expired etc ..

I followed a course and that what the teacher was doing I believe nothing more, so I would appreciate any help, I need it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `CSRF` token while submitting a form since the **'VerifyCsrfToken'** middleware is enabled by default for the web routes in `App/Http/Kernal.php`.

```
<form action="/form" method="POST" >
   @csrf
   <input type="text" name="cih">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And, Welcome to Laravel!